# How to play music in window form application by clicking button C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a button, when the user click the button, the application can play music (played in embedded way or external way are both ok) I am just a rookie on c# and only know how to     create a button Anyone know how to code it?

I found a way to run wav file

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play("wave.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

However, I have added Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" and 
"Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll into reference, the MY is still undefined.

Here is my button function

```
private void musicbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    {
        SoundPlayer snd = null;



            Stream str = Properties.Resources.mysong;
            snd = new SoundPlayer(str);
            snd.Play();

    }
```

Comment: The syntax of the code you've found suggests that it's VB.NET rather than C# - which is why you'll be getting compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SoundPlayer snd = null;

private void musicbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Stream str = Properties.Resources.mySoundFile;
    snd = new SoundPlayer(str);
    snd.Play();
}
```

Inport the wav file into your Project Resources!

Comment: I think your second line should just be: `snd = new SoundPlayer(str);`; otherwise, you're hiding your class level `SoundPlayer` object with a local declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. It look helpful. However, the Stream variable is not defined. The reason is embeedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement. I am not quite understanding this error. May I have your further comment?

Comment: Updated code thx MusiGenesis.. To user1994617 u need this 2 usings directives "System.IO;", "System.Media;"

Comment: Thanks Mikatsu and MusiGenesis.                                      I am edit the code in my question considering the suggestions.     
 But the "Stream" contain error. "Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement." Does it mean this method is not suitable?

Comment: Mikatsu: I have already added using System.Media;
using System.IO;  but it still not work. I am also finding the reason...

Comment: The "Stream" has been already defined. But there is a compilation error: "Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

Comment: Hi All, I have fixed the problem.  Stream str = Properties.Resources.mysong; should not be included into the function and it should be outside the function. Then it works:)  Thanks again to all :)